# How to get direct input from external barcode reader?

Tags: java, api, barcode-scanner

The Scanner is working fine, when any input field is focused, but is it possible to get direct input from scanner in java? without any input field is set to be focused. Does java provide any api or libraray for handling this stuff?

Thanks for your consideration:)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Might depend on your scanner and whether any Java Drivers are available.
Most USB scanners are just keyboard-like input devices that send key strokes. You don't mention what UI library you're using, but maybe you can add a global key listener. Mind you that it probably won't be able to distinguish between keystrokes from the keyboard and scan events.